# Nodejs express handlebars post 404 error '/checkout'

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-404, express-handlebars

I'm building a shopping cart project using Node, Express, handlebars and MongoDB. Currently, when I attempt to submit a form, using Jquery, I receive a 404 error for my '/checkout' file. Originally, I used *return false* to prevent the form from submitting before it receives the data. In an attempt to fix the issue, I tried using *event.preventDefault*, as well. On another forum, someone suggested that my *crsf* protection is not creating the token properly. I worked with the route and added to my view and finally the *hbs* form. None of these attempts appear to have solved my issue.

This is a link to my gist. https://gist.github.com/Satellite9/5e4ce3de5c19cee2f355d872b6d7d3c8

This is the error that my browser sends me.

> *Error: Not Found at C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\app.js:60:13 at
>   Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>   at
>   C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>   at Function.process_params
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>   at
>   C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
>   at Function.handle
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>   at router
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>   at
>   C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>   at Function.process_params
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>   at C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\app.js:51:5 at
>   Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>   at
>   C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>   at Function.process_params
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>   at serveStatic
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>   at
>   C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>   at Function.process_params
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>   at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass
>   (C:\Users\Leimamo\PhpstormProjects\untitled2\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:325:9)
>   *

this is the error that *npm* gives me
Post /checkout 404 206.855 ms -5424

Thank you for any insight you may have.

Killeon

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong verb on index.js. change get->post.

```
router.get('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
......
});
```

to

```
router.post('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
....
});
```

Comment: Hi Fazal, when I change the verb from router.get to router.post, I get a 404 error for the route 'POST /shop/checkout 404'. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I tried a few different ways; changed the route to router.post '/shop/checkout' and still, the error returned a failed search for '/checkout'.

Answer (score 0):

Edit with my demo, man.

```
router.get('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
 //do something
    });

router.post('/checkout', function(req, res, next) {
// do something: get params with req.body
    });
```

> I worked with the route and added to my view and finally the hbs form

**hbs form:** I use route with post when submit form

Comment: Hi Anhlee, I'm not sure that I follow your suggestion. Are you saying that the verb is incorrect, as well? Thank you for responding.